# conditions in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have user control which access the value from querystring and i have made view model acording to this value and when i access the value from query it is not accessing the value of this view model

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Menu.ascx.cs" Inherits="ITClassifieds.Menu" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="ITClassifieds.ViewModels" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="ITClassifieds.Models" %>

<%  ClassifiedEntities db = new ClassifiedEntities();

     string returnvalue = "";
  if (Request.QueryString["resumeid"] != null) {%>

        returnvalue = Request.QueryString["resumeid"].ToString();
        int resume=Convert.ToInt32(returnvalue);
       var resumeed = (from result in db.USP_ResumeWizard_LoadingData(resume)
                                            select new USP_ResumeWizard_LoadingData_Result
                                            {
                                                ExistsResumeTitle = result.ExistsResumeTitle,
                                                ExistsAdditionalInfo = result.ExistsAdditionalInfo,
                                                ExistsEducation = result.ExistsEducation,
                                                ExistsIdealJob = result.ExistsIdealJob,
                                                ExistsAffiliations = result.ExistsAffiliations,
                                                ExistsPublishResume = result.ExistsPublishResume,
                                                ExistsReferences = result.ExistsReferences,
                                                ExistsSkills = result.ExistsSkills,
                                                ExistsTargetLocation = result.ExistsTargetLocation,
                                                ExistsIdealCompany = result.ExistsIdealCompany,
                                                ExistsWorkExperience = result.ExistsWorkExperience,
                                                ExistsWorkStatus = result.ExistsWorkStatus
                                            }).SingleOrDefault(); 
USP_ResumeWizard_LoadingData_Result usp=(USP_ResumeWizard_LoadingData_Result)resumeed;
bool resumetitle = (bool)usp.ExistsResumeTitle;
bool additionalinfo = (bool)usp.ExistsAdditionalInfo;
bool education = (bool)usp.ExistsEducation;
bool idealjob = (bool)usp.ExistsIdealJob ;
bool affiliations = (bool)usp. ExistsAffiliations;
bool publishresume = (bool)usp.ExistsPublishResume;
bool references = (bool)usp.ExistsReferences;
bool skills = (bool)usp.ExistsSkills;
bool targetlocation = (bool)usp.ExistsTargetLocation;
bool idealcompany = (bool)usp.ExistsIdealCompany;
bool workexperience = (bool)usp.ExistsWorkExperience;
bool workstatus=(bool)usp.ExistsWorkStatus;
```

if (resumetitle==true)
 {%>
         
         
              Resumename

                        <% }else{  %>
                        Resumename
                        <% } %>

```
<% }%>
```

it is showing the error end of file expected what can i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a syntax error with your ASP.Net tags.

I suspect the tag at the end of line 8, as below, should not be there.

```
if (Request.QueryString["resumeid"] != null) {%>
```

Comment: what happens if it is null in query string so i have applied that condition

Comment: I  think sipwiz is saying that the `%>` should not be on that line